# Writing and implementing new Java class files during run-time

Tags: java, class, file, runtime

Is it possible to somehow 'import' a new Java class into a running program and make use of it?

Could I have a program create a new File of type '.java' and then include it in the project files and reference it without having to restart the program?

The following is an example of what I mean:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Program {

File JClass = new File("JClass.java");
public static BufferedWriter out = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("JClass.java"));
            out.write("public abstract class JClass {");
            out.newLine();
            out.newLine();
            out.write("    public void printSomething(String a) {");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("        System.out.println(a);");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("    }");
            out.newLine();
            out.write("}");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        //Somehow import JClass.java as a class here

        JClass.printSomething("Yay! It worked!");
    }

}
```

Resulting 'JClass.java' file:

```
public abstract class JClass {

    public void printSomething(String a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Similarly, would it be possible to create a copy of one of the project's source files, edit the code in the file, and then somehow force the changes upon the running program?

I do not care so much about practical application at this point. I am merely exploring different ideas I have had relating to programming. I also understand that this is potential for all sorts of disaster. Editing running code, and including classes on the fly (which I don't imagine would be checked for errors as the other classes are when the project is built), could have very unpredictable results. I merely want to play around with the idea.

That said, if anyone has any HELPFUL warnings or things to look out for, I would appreciate them. Otherwise, I would appreciate if people kept from responding 'This is a bad idea' or 'there are easier and better ways to solve problems'. I am NOT trying to solve a problem with this. I am only exploring the idea.

So, is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javassist will let you modify existing classes and create new classes at run time.
http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/

In the Javassist [tutorial](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html) there is a section for defining a new class from scratch.  Check out the [API](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html) to see how to add new methods and so on.  Check out [CtNewMethod.make](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtNewMethod.html#make%28java.lang.String,%20javassist.CtClass%29) in the Javassist API.

Javassist is what is used by JBoss to implement aspect oriented programming.

You can also check out [EATS](http://code.google.com/p/tantalizing-eats/source/browse/src/com/tantaman/eats/aop/priv/runtime/Eater.java) (the instrument method will be of interest) which makes use of Javassist to add new code to existing methods at runtime.  Eats isn't at a release version, but it works :o

[JPDA](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/) provides some mechanisms for modifying classes that are already loaded by and running in the JVM.

Comment: ASM and CGLIB are similar libraries. This approach is widely used and probably the "best" way to create code on the fly.

Comment: Eww, EATS uses Hungarian Notation. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You should look into on the fly class loading with ClassLoader

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

There are also mechanisms you can use to compile classes, but that's probably not going to be AS useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want a Compiler - look at java.lang.Compiler:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Compiler.html

You can load a different class this way by compiling a new .class file.

This does not let you change a loaded class. To do that you also need a java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer and that has to be specified on the command-line at runtime.

To answer some of your other questions:

- If a file is compiled from .java it will go through the same checks as one compiled elsewhere.
- If you create the byte code using suitable tools (BCEL or ASM for example) then it still goes through multiple checks to prove it is internally consistent.
- If you change a running classes, you are limited in what you can change.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing one more out there: the [Eclipse Java Compiler](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/). Unlike BCEL, ASM, or Jasmin, you don't need to know assembly. ECJ is just a Java compiler written in Java.