# Is there an equivalent to Python's `type(name, bases, dict)` in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

How can I dynamically create a class in Java, if I only now the parent class at runtime via reflection?

```java
// I only know what ParentClass is at runtime
// but I know that ParentClass implements SomeInterface.
public class MyClass extends ParentClass implements SomeInterface {
    // I know the method I want to override,
    // and that ParentClass has a no-argument constructor.
    @Override
    public int method(int arg) {
        return 42 * arg;
    }
}
```

E.g. in Python you could use

```py
MyClass = type("MyClass", (ParentClass,), {
    'method': lambda self, arg: 42 * arg
})
# or even easier
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    def name(self, arg):
        return 42 * arg
```

So, is there an equivalent to Python's [`type(name, bases, dict)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) in Java?

Comment: Why do you need to do this at runtime? Look into `Proxy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct/easy way to do this in java. We need to create class file and load it to classloader.  You can refer the following answer [Writing and implementing new Java class files during run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493784/writing-and-implementing-new-java-class-files-during-run-time/5493858#5493858). Several third party libraries like **ASM, CGLIB, JAVASSIST** helps in creating code on the fly.